# Warum sind "totlachen, kaputtlachen,…" reflexiv, und "lachen" nicht?

Tags: verb, reflexive

Hier auf dieser Seite habe ich einen Kommentar gesehen, in dem es behauptet wird, Komposita mit *lachen* reflexiv seien bzw. reflexiv sein können. Warum?

Answer (score 7):

Im übertragenen Sinne wird jemand durch das Lachen getötet. Da dieser jemand immer der Lachende selbst ist, tötet er sich selbst. Er lacht *sich* also tot.

Analog für "kaputt"; hier eine Gegenprobe: Sie lacht tot. / Er lacht den Postboten kaputt.

Answer (score 5):

Sie können reflexiv sein, weil sich das Lachen bzw. der Grund des Lachens auch auf den Lachenden selber beziehen kann. Hingegen bezeichnet das Verb „lachen“ allein nur die „Aktivität“ selber, ohne zugleich eine „Richtung“ des Lachens, seinen Grund oder seine Intention anzugeben.

Man muss aber aufpassen: Komposita mit „lachen“ *können* reflexiv sein, *müssen* aber nicht. Es kommt auf das Präfix an. „Auslachen“ beispielsweise bezieht sich meist auf eine andere Person (*transitiv*), „totlachen“ oder „kaputtlachen“ auf den Lachenden selbst (*refexiv*).

Answer (score 2):

Beide Verben sind zunächst im Gegensatz zu "lachen" telisch. Das heißt, sie haben ein "Ziel". Hier sind das die Adjektive/Präfixe. "Lachen" hat kein "ziel". Du machst es, und danach nicht.
Das reicht aber noch nicht. Du kannst beide Verben abstrakt als "Produktionsverben" kategorisieren und das generische "machen" einsetzen. Solche Verben brauchen eigentlich immer ein Objekt.... eben genau wie "machen".

- Ich mache tot (durch lachen).
- Ich mache kaputt (durch lachen).

Welche Objekte kann man einsetzen? Mit viel Fantasie geht da schon was.

- Ich habe den Singer-Song-Writer Song bei der Open Stage kaputt gelacht.

Das könnte heißen, dass du es so scheiße fandest, dass du die ganze Zeit gelacht hast, und damit den Künstler immens gestört.
Die reflexive, metaphorische Lesart ist aber weitaus naheliegender.